# Optimizing joins in a postgres/postgis query

Tags: postgresql, join, search, eloquent, postgis

I'm trying to optimize my Postgres query. I'm running into problems with some of the joins here. My main issue is around the filter `h.type='inNetwork'` and my geometry search `ST_Intersects(ST_MakeValid(ser.boundaries)::geography, ST_MakeValid(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJson(<INSERT_GEOMETRY_JSON>))`. Something about that specific filter increase the search time by ~10x. The other filters don't seem to have much of an effect on the search speed. As a side note, there are additional filters that are used conditionally and that's why some of the join tables here seem irrelevant.

Query in question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.id, r.profitability
FROM rolloff_pricing as r
LEFT JOIN service_areas ser on r.service_area_id = ser.id
LEFT JOIN sizes as s on r.size_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN sizes as sa on r.sell_as = sa.id
LEFT JOIN waste_types w on w.id = r.waste_type_id
LEFT JOIN regions reg on reg.id = ser.region_id
LEFT JOIN haulers h on h.id = reg.hauler_id
LEFT JOIN current_availability ca on ca.region_id = reg.id
LEFT JOIN regions_availability ra on ra.region_id = reg.id
LEFT JOIN current_availability_new_deliveries cand on ca.id = cand.current_availability_id and r.size_id = cand.size_id
LEFT JOIN exceptions ex on ex.region_id = reg.id
WHERE ser.active is true
and ST_Intersects(ST_MakeValid(ser.boundaries)::geography, ST_MakeValid(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJson('{
    "type": "POINT",
    "coordinates": [
        "-95.3595563",
        "29.7634871"
    ]
}'),4326))::geography)
and h.active is true
and ra.delivery_type='newDeliveries'
and h.type='inNetwork'
GROUP BY r.id ORDER BY profitability desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 8 ROWS ONLY
```

Here is the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`:

```
Limit  (cost=246.23..246.29 rows=8 width=21) (actual time=3711.860..3711.866 rows=8 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=15048
  ->  Unique  (cost=246.23..246.29 rows=8 width=21) (actual time=3711.859..3711.860 rows=8 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=15048
        ->  Sort  (cost=246.23..246.25 rows=8 width=21) (actual time=3711.858..3711.858 rows=8 loops=1)
"              Sort Key: r.profitability DESC, r.id"
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB
              Buffers: shared hit=15048
              ->  Group  (cost=246.07..246.11 rows=8 width=21) (actual time=3711.820..3711.841 rows=48 loops=1)
                    Group Key: r.id
                    Buffers: shared hit=15048
                    ->  Sort  (cost=246.07..246.09 rows=8 width=21) (actual time=3711.817..3711.823 rows=216 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: r.id
                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 41kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=15048
                          ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=154.30..245.95 rows=8 width=21) (actual time=3711.508..3711.745 rows=216 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: ((reg.id)::text = (ex.region_id)::text)
                                Buffers: shared hit=15048
                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=150.45..242.05 rows=8 width=37) (actual time=3711.490..3711.705 rows=144 loops=1)
                                      Hash Cond: ((ra.region_id)::text = (reg.id)::text)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=15045
                                      ->  Seq Scan on regions_availability ra  (cost=0.00..89.11 rows=643 width=16) (actual time=0.006..0.186 rows=643 loops=1)
                                            Filter: ((delivery_type)::text = 'newDeliveries'::text)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 1286
                                            Buffers: shared hit=65
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=150.34..150.34 rows=9 width=53) (actual time=3711.461..3711.461 rows=144 loops=1)
                                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 21kB
                                            Buffers: shared hit=14980
                                            ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=73.72..150.34 rows=9 width=53) (actual time=3711.218..3711.442 rows=144 loops=1)
                                                  Hash Cond: ((ca.region_id)::text = (reg.id)::text)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=14980
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on current_availability ca  (cost=0.00..69.02 rows=2002 width=32) (actual time=0.009..0.124 rows=2002 loops=1)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=49
                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=73.68..73.68 rows=3 width=69) (actual time=3711.173..3711.173 rows=48 loops=1)
                                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=14931
                                                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..73.68 rows=3 width=69) (actual time=2262.438..3711.145 rows=48 loops=1)
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=14931
                                                              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.55..44.90 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=2262.424..3710.955 rows=7 loops=1)
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=14877
                                                                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..38.20 rows=3 width=16) (actual time=0.012..4.723 rows=609 loops=1)
                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=1418
                                                                          ->  Seq Scan on haulers h  (cost=0.00..21.60 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.698 rows=439 loops=1)
                                                                                Filter: ((active IS TRUE) AND ((type)::text = 'inNetwork'::text))
                                                                                Rows Removed by Filter: 89
                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=15
                                                                          ->  Index Scan using regions_hauler_id_idx on regions reg  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=439)
                                                                                Index Cond: ((hauler_id)::text = (h.id)::text)
                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=1403
                                                                    ->  Index Scan using service_areas_region_id_idx on service_areas ser  (cost=0.28..2.22 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=6.035..6.085 rows=0 loops=609)
                                                                          Index Cond: ((region_id)::text = (reg.id)::text)
"                                                                          Filter: ((active IS TRUE) AND ((st_makevalid(boundaries))::geography && '0101000020E610000087646DF802D757C0FA6AFDE373C33D40'::geography) AND (_st_distance((st_makevalid(boundaries))::geography, '0101000020E610000087646DF802D757C0FA6AFDE373C33D40'::geography, '0'::double precision, false) < '1.00000000000000008e-05'::double precision))"
                                                                          Rows Removed by Filter: 3
                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=13459
                                                              ->  Index Scan using rolloff_pricing_service_area_id_idx on rolloff_pricing r  (cost=0.29..28.70 rows=8 width=83) (actual time=0.013..0.019 rows=7 loops=7)
                                                                    Index Cond: ((service_area_id)::text = (ser.id)::text)
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=54
                                ->  Hash  (cost=3.38..3.38 rows=38 width=48) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=39 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                      ->  Seq Scan on exceptions ex  (cost=0.00..3.38 rows=38 width=48) (actual time=0.003..0.007 rows=39 loops=1)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning Time: 1.031 ms
Execution Time: 3711.956 ms
```

My understanding of what's happening here is that my filter is bringing in additional rows (the large majority of the `h` table is true for the condition `h.type='inNetwork'`, which is making my geometry query run for a much larger set of rows than intended.

Something that I've tried is putting the geometry query into a subquery (because the geometry query actually runs pretty quickly itself) to get a set of `r.id`'s that I could use in an `where in` clause. This seems to not work as well though. Here is my modified query that also is too slow:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.id, r.profitability
FROM rolloff_pricing as r
LEFT JOIN service_areas ser on r.service_area_id = ser.id
LEFT JOIN sizes as s on r.size_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN sizes as sa on r.sell_as = sa.id
RIGHT JOIN waste_types w on w.id = r.waste_type_id
RIGHT JOIN regions reg on reg.id = ser.region_id
RIGHT JOIN haulers h on h.id = ser.hauler_id
RIGHT JOIN current_availability ca on ca.region_id = reg.id
RIGHT JOIN regions_availability ra on ra.region_id = reg.id
LEFT JOIN current_availability_new_deliveries cand on ca.id = cand.current_availability_id and r.size_id = cand.size_id
RIGHT JOIN exceptions ex on ex.region_id = reg.id
WHERE r.id in (
    select r2.id
    from rolloff_pricing as r2
    LEFT JOIN service_areas ser2 on r2.service_area_id = ser2.id
    WHERE
    ST_Intersects(ST_MakeValid(ser2.boundaries)::geography, ST_MakeValid(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJson('{
        "type": "POINT",
        "coordinates": [
            "-95.3595563",
            "29.7634871"
        ]
    }'),4326))::geography)
    and ser2.active is true
)
and h.active is true
and ra.delivery_type='newDeliveries'
and h.type='inNetwork'
GROUP BY r.id ORDER BY profitability desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 8 ROWS ONLY
```

It's interesting to me because the subquery here resolves by itself very quickly. And if I sub out the subquery for the returned results, the whole thing resolves very quickly as well. So I'm not sure how to approach this exactly. My next guess is to just run a completely seperate query for the `r.id`s and then pass them through to the "main" query.

Maybe relevant info: this query is being generated and executed in an eloquent-based api

How can I go about approaching improving the speed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the large majority of the h table is true for the condition h.type='inNetwork', which is making my geometry query run for a much larger set of rows than intended.

I don't understand.  If most of the table meets the condition `h.active is true and h.type='inNetwork'`, then most of the table gets processed.  What else could have possibly been intended? The estimate there is pretty horrible (estimated rows 2, actual 439) but that must be just because your stats are horribly out of date.  There is really no good reason for the estimate to be off by so much. You should run VACUUM ANALYZE on all tables involved in this query, after making sure there are no transactions being held open. If it doesn't fix the query directly, it will at least produce plans which are easier to understand.

```
->  Index Scan using service_areas_region_id_idx on service_areas ser  (cost=0.28..2.22 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=6.035..6.085 rows=0 loops=609)
    Index Cond: ((region_id)::text = (reg.id)::text)
    Filter: ((active IS TRUE) AND ((st_makevalid(boundaries))::geography && '0101000020E610000087646DF802D757C0FA6AFDE373C33D40'::geography) AND (_st_distance((st_makevalid(boundaries))::geography, '0101000020E610000087646DF802D757C0FA6AFDE373C33D40'::geography, '0'::double precision, false) < '1.00000000000000008e-05'::double precision))"
    Rows Removed by Filter: 3
    Buffers: shared hit=13459
```

This is the one place which takes pretty much all of the time.  And it is hard to understand what it is actually doing.  Why on earth would it take 13459 buffers hits to run this scan 609 times?  that is 22 buffers for each loop, but descending an index should only take 3 to 4 buffer accesses.  You could be filtering out a lot of rows due to the filter condition, but in that case Rows Removed by Filter would need to be a lot more than 3.  Maybe the index is stuffed full of dead entries, which then get filtered out but don't get tabulated in 'Rows Removed by Filter'.  (A VACUUM when there are no transactions being held open would fix that).  Or maybe the geometry column is very large and so gets TOASTed over many pages.

And to be clear here, I'm not saying the large number of buffer accesses are *causing* the slowness, they are all "buffer hits" afterall and so should be fast. But it is an oddity that should be investigated.

Comment: Perhaps `boundaries` has lots of vertices.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  Yes, that would explain both the slowness (CPU intensive to process those vertices) and the large number of buffers accesses (because the the geometry values could be toasted over multiple pages)

Comment: Ahhh. Running the `VACUUM ANALYZE` command seemed to fix the issue I was running into here. I still have some slowness from the api side I'm trying to figure out but this helped my direct api query. I'm now getting sub 200ms queries instead of 3-7s queries for this. I'm assuming the issue is because the `h.type` column is a new column as of ~month ago and the index needed to reanalyze?

Comment: @AlexDeCamillo When you do `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ...`, that new column doesn't have stats created for it, even though it would benefit from them (and even though the system knows what they should be--clearly all rows have the same value, the default for the new column).  And then if the table is not updated much after that, an auto-ANALYZE might never get scheduled on it, either.  So it is the column, not the index, in need of the analyze.